# How are two definitions of quasi-convexity equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, optimization, convex-analysis

Why are these two definitions equivalent? (Assuming $C$ is convex)

- $f: C \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is quasi-convex if for any $x, y \in  C$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$,
  $$ f((1-\lambda)x + \lambda y) \leq \max\{f(x), f(y)\} .$$
- $f: C \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ is quasi-convex if for any $\alpha \in  \mathbb{R}$, $\operatorname{Lev} (f, \alpha) $ is convex.

Where $\operatorname{Lev} (f, \alpha) $ is defined as: $$ \{x \in S: f(x) < \alpha \}$$

I was successful to show that if we have the first definition, it implies the second one, but got stuck on the reverse side.

assume $ x, y \in \operatorname{Lev} (f, \alpha) $ so: $$f(x) < \alpha,$$
$$f(y) < \alpha.$$

Then we have:
$$ max\{f(x), f(y)\} < \alpha $$
So by the first definition, we have:
$$ f((1-\lambda)x + \lambda y) < \alpha $$
Which implies that:

$$ ((1-\lambda)x + \lambda y) \in \operatorname{Lev}(f, \alpha) .$$

Comment: @BrunoB corrected.

Comment: @Mittens it is the level set, I will add it as quickly as I can.

Comment: What have you tried? Can you at least show that one definition implies the other for example?

Comment: @BrunoB yes, given the first one, the second one is pretty easy. The problem is the other way around. should I include this in the question as well?

Comment: Yes, that would be better. That way you'll be less prone to getting downvotes or the like.

Comment: @BrunoB Ok, I will edit it now.

Comment: Besides avoiding downvotes, by explicitly explaining what you already know versus what you do not yet know, you avoid wasting the time and energy of everyone involved.

Comment: It's not just for a "game" of upvotes and downvotes as Lee stated, writing what you've tried allows us to better help you and where, and allows you to better see where exactly you are stuck so that you can communicate clearly what you wish to be helped with. Sometimes you also just answer your own question before finishing writing in the process, it's happened to me once or twice :)

Comment: @LeeMosher Ok, I was not aware. I am editing right now.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks man, I corrected it.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks, I will correct it now.

Comment: Related: [Difference in Definitions of Quasiconvexity](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867549/difference-in-definitions-of-quasiconvexity)

Comment: @Mittens: Surely related, but IMO not an exact duplicate. Using the notation of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/867549/42969, *this* question is why (1) and (2) are equivalent, whereas the referenced question asks why (2) and (3) are equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to show that the second condition implies the first, assume that $\operatorname{Lev}(f, \alpha) $ is convex for all $\alpha \in \Bbb R$.

Now let $x, y \in C$ and $0 \le \lambda \le 1$.

For arbitrary $\epsilon > 0$ set $\alpha = \max(f(x), f(y)) + \epsilon$. Then
$$
 f(x) < \alpha \implies x \in \operatorname{Lev}(f, \alpha)
$$
and
$$
 f(y) < \alpha \implies y \in \operatorname{Lev}(f, \alpha)
$$
and therefore, since $\operatorname{Lev}(f, \alpha)$ is convex,
$$
 (1-\lambda)x + \lambda y  \in \operatorname{Lev}(f, \alpha) \, .
$$
So
$$
f((1-\lambda)x + \lambda y) < \alpha = \max(f(x), f(y)) + \epsilon
$$
for all $\epsilon > 0$, which implies
$$
f((1-\lambda)x + \lambda y) \le  \max(f(x), f(y)) \, .
$$
This proves that $f$ is quasi-convex.